# How To Make Palm Trees In Python Turtle

Tags: python, tree, python-turtle

I need 2 palm trees looking like these but I don't know how to do the leaves
I have tried many different codes to try ad do this but I always stuff up on the leaves
[This picture shows want I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCH6Z.png)
Please help me, any responses help.
I have no code to send my tries but I just want to know how to do it

Comment: Please share your attempts and ask a specific question about the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.